# Assign a double value to a TextView?

Tags: java, android, xml

how do I assign a double value to a TextView? This is the code:

```
if(condition()) {

    TV=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView); 
    TV.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>TEXT 01 </b>"));

}
else {
    TV=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView); 

    TV.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>TEXT 02</b>"));

}

if(condition) {
    TV=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView); 

    TV.setText(Html.fromHtml("TEXT 03"));

}
else {
    TV=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView); 

    TV.setText(Html.fromHtml("TEXT 04"));

}
```

If I run the application and both conditions are true return as I visualize only the last written words TEXT 03. How do I view also TEXT 01?

Comment: You are saying set Text 01 and then again you are saying Text 03, which one of these you want really on condition true?

Comment: Do you want to append "TEXT 03" to "TEXT 01", so the end result is something similar to `<b>TEXT 01 TEXT 02</b>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the same `TextView`. You need to create a second `TextView` or append the `String` that you want.

```
    if(condition()) {

        TV=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView); // each time you call this you reintializ
                                                   // the TextView then set new text to it
                                                   // you don't append the text
        TV.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>TEXT 01 </b>"));

   }
    else {
        TV=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView); 

        TV.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>TEXT 02</b>"));

    } 

    if(condition) {
        TV=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView); 

        TV.setText(Html.fromHtml("TEXT 03"));

    }
    else {
         TV=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView); 

        TV.setText(Html.fromHtml("TEXT 04"));

  }
```

To make this much simpler initialize your `TextView` once and append the text in the second condition

```
TV=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
if (condition())
{
    TV.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>TEXT 01 </b>"));
else
{
    TV.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>TEXT 02</b>"));
}

if (condition)
{
    TV.append(Html.fromHtml("TEXT 03"));
}
else
{
    TV.append(Html.fromHtml("TEXT 04"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only see "TEXT 03" on the TextView because you call setText("TEXT 03") after setText(TEXT 01") if they are both true then TEXT 03 overwrites TEXT 01.
You should change the logic for example:

```
if (condition1 && condition3) {
    tv.setText("TEXT 03" + "TEXT 01");
}
```